# Maintaining Consistent Header Height in React with Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working on a React project with Next.js and using Tailwind CSS for styling. I have a header that is intended to occupy 25% of the page height. On most pages, such as the home, contact, and tags pages, it works as expected. However, when I navigate to specific pages, like opening a song/children, the content pushes the header to the top of the page.

I want to make sure that no matter which page I'm on, the header always takes up 25% of the page's height. I've tried different methods, but I'm having trouble making it consistent.

Header Component

```
function Header (){
    return(
        <div className="bg-sky-900 h-1/4">
        </div>
    )
};

export default Header
```

Layout Component

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="h-full">
      <body className={`${inter.className} h-full flex flex-col`}>
        <Header />
        <nav>
          <Link href="/">Home</Link>
          <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
          <Link href="/tags">Tags</Link>
        </nav>
        <div className="flex-1">{children}</div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Song Component

```
function CompositionPage(
....
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{songFound.name}</h1>
        {songFoundCategory && (
          <Link href={`/compositions/${songFoundCategory.categoryRef}`}>
            {songFoundCategory.name}
          </Link>
        )}
        <div>
          {songFoundTag.map((tag) => {
            return (
              <Link href={`../../tags/${tag.tagRef}`} key={tag.tagRef}>
                #{tag.rusName}
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div>
          {relatedCompositions &&
            relatedCompositions.map((song) => {
              return (
                <Link
                  href={`/compositions/${song.category}/${song.compositionRef}`}
                  key={song.compositionRef}
                >
                  {song.name}
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          <div>
            <Player src={songFound.mp3Url} />
          </div>
          <PDFViewer url={songFound.pdfUrl} />
        </div>
        <PrevNextComp composition={songFound} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PDF Viewer Component CSS

```
.viewer {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.viewer canvas {
  height: unset !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: The song component is the content that push the header into the top of the page.